# Order does not exist in Magento but customer has paid for it

Tags: php, magento, paypal

One situation was happened in my website which build in Magento.

Situation is : A customer added products in cart, he bought products using Paypal express checkout payment method. he did the transaction in Paypal, money was deducted from his account but the order was not created in Magento due to unknown issue(I think due to internet issue on client machine or our server issue).

What I want do now : I got his cart detail from sales_flat_quote and sales_flat_quote_item table. I want to generate an order using this detail using Paypal payment method progamatically . customer has send us the Paypal transaction id, invoice id from Paypal and also shipping address.

Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Comment: just open up the order via quote in in the backend and make it into an order and put it as paid. You might have to put in the order id in the url manually. Just open up an existing quote and change the quote id.

Comment: Customer ordered as a guest, so I didn't have quote in backend.

Comment: You said you had his cart details. Those cart details have a quote number. use that number int he url to open up his quote to turn into an order.

Comment: Yes. I fetched the quote_id from sales_flat_order. In which url you want me to put quote_id. Please mention

Comment: Also I saw that details were saved in 'sales_flat_quote_address' and 'sales_flat_quote_payment' table. But unable to save in sales_flat_order